# I use Flutter (Image picker) I dont find image source

Tags: flutter, image

I am first time learning flutter and am a beginner. I use Image picker but i dont find image source. I can't find the source of the image I attached.

The emulator shows me the path to the image like this:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.fotoyukle/cache/e50f0995-caaf-4391-864b-0d0b017a5eed/landscape-3127859_1920.jpg
```

Here's the real source of the picture:

```
storage/emulated/0/Download/
```

My codes:

```
Future getImage(ImageSource source) async{
final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
if(image == null) return;
final imageTemporary = io.File(image.path);

setState(() {
this._image = imageTemporary;
print(_image!.path);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the emulator you won't be able to use any of your local images, you'll have to use the one which is used inside your emulator. For best practices try using an actual device connected with a USB cable in debugging mode.